# Custom UITableViewCell is not reused in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` and `UITableViewCell`. This cell contains three text fields. Each text field has a tag. The cell is created as the following.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"reuseMyCell";

    cell = (TimeInserTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimeInsertCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){

            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[TimeInserTableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (TimeInserTableViewCell *) currentObject;
                if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString: CellIdentifier]) {

                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }        

    cell.taskNameField.delegate=self;
    cell.startTime.delegate=self;
    cell.endTime.delegate=self;        

    return cell;
}
```

My problem is the following: when I enter text in the first text field and I scroll, the previous text field text is replacing in other cells too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check weather you are using reuse identifier in your custom cell IB.